# How to replace a None value with a specific value in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql, isnull

I'm trying to replace 'None' values in a column with a specific value.
I want instead of having 'None' I'd like to have the language 'English' which is the one that corresponds to the country USA.

Here is one of the queries I'm trying but I run out of ideas:

```
SELECT pais, Language
ISNULL (Language, 'None') AS 'English'
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT pais, Name, Language
FROM CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN final
ON CLIENTE.PAIS = final.Name
)
```

I attach this picture so that you can see what I'm trying, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the value is really `NULL`, then you would use:

```
select pais,
       coalesce(language, 'English') as language
from . . .
```

If the language is really `'None'`, then you would use a `case` expression:

```
select pais,
       (case when language = 'None' then 'English' else language end) as language
from . . .
```